# Meaning of 'Local' density in Liouville's theorem

Tags: classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, terminology, definition, locality

Liouville's theorem is commonly stated as
$$\frac{d\rho}{dt} = \frac{\partial{\rho}}{\partial{t}} + [\rho, H]$$

Where, $H$ is Hamiltonian of the system, $\rho$ is the density, $[...]$ is the usual Poisson bracket.

My Textbook (name given below) interprets the theorem as

> "The "local" density of the representative points, as viewed by an observer moving with a representative point, stays constant in time."

My question is that if an observer is moving with the representative point $(q_i, p_i)$ then wouldn't the density he will observe for the representative points in the whole phase space be basically looking constant in time to him? (If there's some reason for the localisation condition to be introduced in the statement, then what is the *extent* of this locality?)

**References**

1. *Statistical Mechanics - R.K. Pathria, Paul D. Beale*

Comment: More on the [definition of local](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition+locality).

Comment: Are you completely current on the [Lagrangian description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_and_Eulerian_specification_of_the_flow_field) of fluid flow, in sharp contrast to the Eulerian picture?

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(Hamiltonian)).

Comment: No, not at all. I learnt the qualitative definitions but that's it.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Advanced_Classical_Mechanics/Liouville%27s_theorem) might be useful.

Comment: Okay, I didn't think of it in terms of Energy distributions. Due to inhomogeneous distributions of Energy and if (in this case it's true) the Hamiltonian is conserved, then there will be less particles in the Phase space in the *high energy* area as opposed to the low energy areas as a single path cannot cross the two areas as to conserve the energy. Hence, the non-homogeneity of density. Thanks a lot.

Comment: $\rho$ represents an *ensemble,* which essentially is a measure in the phase space. It's not a dynamical variable, but a weight in phase space (Balescu, *Equilibrium and Nonequilibrium Statistical Mechanics,* John Wiley & Sons, 1975, Sec. 2.2.) How an "observer" can sit somewhere and "view" a piece of the phase space evolve with its abstract statistical measure I cannot figure out. And the density changes from point to point. Otherwise it would be singular. This is clearly stated in last reference provided by @CosmasZachos.

Comment: I think the authors in my reference would have used the words "observe" and "view" in a pedagogical sense and not to be taken seriously *at the point* of getting introduced to these concepts. Other than that, @CosmosZachos point and your mathematical argument have given a clear understanding of the concept.

Comment: To be rigorous, the Liouville's theorem is $$\frac{d\rho}{dt} = \frac{\partial{\rho}}{\partial{t}} + [\rho, H]=0$$

Otherwise, it is just the time-derivative of a multi-variable function.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a pedagogic way of "understanding" Liouville's theorem. Whereas the global "shape" of the probability distribution changes with time, if you place a walker in $q_0,p_0$ with a probability $\rho(q_0,p_0)dp_0dp_0$ in its backpack, this walker will always carry the same probability $\rho(q_t,p_t)dp_tdp_t=\rho(q_0,p_0)dp_0dp_0$ through its Hamiltonian evolution.